# print the values in dictionary without the empty list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a data of follow:

```
d = d = [ {
  "test" : [ {
    "win" : {
      "number" : 0
    },
    "taken" : [ {
      "id" : "0",
      "library" : [ ]
    } ]
  }, {
    "win" : {
      "number" : 1
    },
    "taken" : [ {
      "id" : "1",
      "library" : [ {
        "takenid" : "2",
        "lib" : "man"
      } ]
    }, {
      "id" : "2",
    } ]
  }, {
    "chunk" : {
      "number" : 2
    },
    "taken" : [ {
      "id" : "3",
      "library" : [ {
        "takenid" : "0",
        "lib" : "woman"
      }, {
        "takenid" : "1",
        "lib" : "ghost"
      }, {
        "takenid" : "4",
        "lib" : "monster"
      } ]
    }, {
      "id" : "4"
    } ]
  } ]
} ]
```

I wanted to print all the values for "lib" dictionary but not the empty list. In my code, I will check the total "id" and compare it with the "takenid" then add new "takenid" based on the missing values. After that, I wish to create a dictionary that have the form of this {id:{takenid:lib}} but excluding the empty list(the newly added "takenid" and "lib").

Below is my script code:

```
acom = []
lemmas = []
ordering = []
sort = []      

check = 0
for x in d[0]["test"]:
    for y in x["taken"]:
        if "id" in y:
            check += 1

value = []
#Calculate the number of "takenid"
for x in d[0]["test"]:
    for y in x["taken"]:
        if "library" in y:
            for u in y["library"]:
                value.append(int(u["takenid"]))
#Find the difference between the "id" and "takenid"                
missing = (set(range(check)) - set(value))
missing = list(missing)
#print(missing)

for x in d[0]["test"]:
    for y in x["taken"]:
        if "library" in y:
            y["library"].append({"takenid": "%s" % missing[0], "lib": []})
    break                    
#Create a dictionary                             
for x in d[0]["test"]:
    for y in x["taken"]:
        if "library" in y:
            for u in y["library"]:
                if "[]" not in u["lib"]:
                    #if "[]" not in uu:
                       ordering.append({y["id"]:{u["takenid"]:u["lib"]}})



#print(ordering)
```

However, my code takes in the empty list and printed this output:

Current output:

```
[{'0': {'3': []}}, {'1': {'2': 'man'}}, {'3': {'0': 'woman'}}, {'3': {'1': 'ghost'}}, {'3': {'4': 'monster'}}]
```

I am hoping to create a dictionary without the empty list. Is it possible to do so?

Expected output:

```
[ {'1': {'2': 'man'}}, {'3': {'0': 'woman'}}, {'3': {'1': 'ghost'}}, {'3': {'4': 'monster'}}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>maybe `"[]"` caused the problem. change `"[]"` to `[]`</del>

change `if "[]" not in u["lib"]:` to `if u["lib"]:` will do the work.

Explanation:

`"[]" not in u["lib"]` means `'find substring "[]" in u["lib"]'`. but in your `u["lib"]` contains only string or empty list. so just **evaluate value exists** will give you correct answer.

Comment: If I changed it to [] then I get this. TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list

Comment: sorry. change ```if "[]" not in u["lib"]:``` to ```if u["lib"]:``` will do the work.

Comment: ```"[]" not in u["lib"]``` means 'find substring "[]" in u["lib"]'. but in your ```u["lib"]``` contains only string or empty list. so just evaluate value exists will give you correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Shorter alternative:

```
[{baz['id']: {quux['takenid']: quux['lib']}}
    for foo in d
    for k, v in foo.items()
    for bar in v
    for kk, vv in bar.items()
    for baz in vv if 'library' in baz and baz['library']
    for quux in baz['library']
]
# => [{'1': {'2': 'man'}}, {'3': {'0': 'woman'}}, {'3': {'1': 'ghost'}}, {'3': {'4': 'monster'}}]
```

Here, `if 'library' in baz and baz['library']` will check that the `library` key exists and is not empty.

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me a shorter version sir. I will take mark of it